# Shopify check out API error "This action requires merchant approval for write_checkouts scope"

Tags: flutter, shopify, checkout, shopify-api

I'm encountering an issue when making a POST request to the Shopify API for creating a checkout. The error message I'm receiving is:

"[API] This action requires merchant approval for write_checkouts scope."

Here are the details of my setup:

Shopify API Version: admin/api/2023-07/checkouts.json
Headers:
"X-Shopify-Access-Token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"Content-Type": "application/json"
"cookie": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
I'm trying to checkout the cart items, but it seems that the required write_checkouts scope is missing. However, I couldn't find an option for write_checkouts in the Shopify Admin API Configuration.

Here are the steps I've taken:

Checked App Permissions: I'm using a third-party app to access the Shopify store. I've verified that the app has been configured with the necessary permissions.

Private Apps: I've created a private app in Shopify and ensured that it has the required permissions.

OAuth Scopes: I've selected the write_checkouts scope when configuring my app.

Access Token: I'm using the correct access token associated with my app.

API Version: I'm using admin/api/2023-07/checkouts.json, which appears to be a future date in the Shopify Admin API. Is this version and endpoint combination supported by Shopify?

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully create checkouts via the Shopify API.

Thank you for your assistance.

Posting this refined text on Stack Overflow should provide the necessary context for the community to help you address your Shopify API issue effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin API does not do **checkouts**. I think you want to shift your focus to Storefront API as that is indeed used to create checkouts. So in your code, instead of trying to create a checkout via /admin/api, try using the correct Storefront API URL and then maybe you will see that indeed, you asked for write_checkout functionality and indeed, it was granted and that it works. Attention to details!

Comment: i want to checkout with customer_Id but in storefront API I am not able to send customer Id in storefront API

Comment: Apparently you no longer use a customer ID with checkouts, but instead you use what Shopify calls a buyerIdentity.

Comment: The problem is solved now I am using admin graphql APIs to create a orders it will accept customer identification with order

Comment: I have another issue you can help with that . I want to get details about customer orders but I want details by phone because I am working with phone numbers I think storefront API cannot provide details of customer

Comment: It took one second of checking the Storefront API documentation to see that indeed that API offers up access to customers.